# Cornerstone,add some files,but don't commit

Tags: svn, cornerstone

Cornerstone 3.0.1, I add some file and commit my code,then,show me four options:.., ignore,add to working copy,commit any way.
First time, I choosed ignore.so, I can't search my files of added in cornerstone,but local exist. When I commited,the sever don't have these files.
Now,local have these file,but cornerstone nonrecognition.
I change these file's name,cornerstone reveal A.
Why... Do you meet this case?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take a moment to read up on how to write a [mcve] As its written its very hard to work out what your problem is & how to recreate it.

Comment: a screenshot will also help. It is not clear what options you ask about.